# Hazelcast suddenly started extreme amounts of logging

Tags: hazelcast

We have a hazelcast cluster (version 3.12.5) with 3 nodes with the CP subsystem enabled. This cluster suddenly started generating enormous amounts of logging (in excess of 500MB per day) whereas previously we only got several tens of MB's per day.

The loglines keep repeating themselves. We see the following lines:

```
2021-02-23 16:24:39,150 DEBUG [36 hz.hzserver.partition-operation.thread-0] com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService [xxx-xxxxxx]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] RaftNode[CPGroupId{name='METADATA', seed=0, commitIndex=0}] does not exist. Asking to the METADATA CP group...
2021-02-23 16:24:39,150 WARN  [36 hz.hzserver.partition-operation.thread-0] com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService [xxx-xxxxxx]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] RaftNode[CPGroupId{name='METADATA', seed=0, commitIndex=0}] does not exist to handle: AppendRequest ...
2021-02-23 16:24:39,150 DEBUG [34 hz.hzserver.response-0] com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftInvocationManager [xxx-xxxxxx]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Setting known leader for raft: CPGroupId{name='METADATA', seed=0, commitIndex=0} to CPMember{uuid=5dbbb895-be7e-45ab-8b90-4da2a41eb181, address=[yyyy-yyyyyy]:5701}
2021-02-23 16:24:39,775 DEBUG [36 hz.hzserver.partition-operation.thread-0] com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService [xxx-xxxxxxx]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] RaftNode[CPGroupId{name='default', seed=0, commitIndex=15}] does not exist. Asking to the METADATA CP group...
2021-02-23 16:24:39,775 WARN  [36 hz.hzserver.partition-operation.thread-0] com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService [xxx-xxxxxxx]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] RaftNode[CPGroupId{name='default', seed=0, commitIndex=15}] does not exist to handle: AppendRequest{leader=CPMember{uuid=79d87749-5f9c-43fb-b3ef-78cabed2a623, address=[xxx-xxxxx]:5701}, term=1, prevLogTerm=1, prevLogIndex=521, leaderCommitIndex=2606, entries=[LogEntry{term=1, index=522, operation=com.hazelcast.cp.internal.datastructures.atomicref.operation.GetOp{serviceName='hz:raft:atomicRefService', name=foo}}, LogEntry{term=1, index=523, operation=com.hazelcast.cp.internal.datastructures.atomicref.operation.SetOp{serviceName='hz:raft:atomicRefService', name=foo}}, LogEntry{term=1, index=524, .....
```

We don't understand what is going on here, so I hope someone here can explain.

**UPDATE 1**

CP Subsystem Config:

```
cpSubsystemConfig.setCPMemberCount(3);
cpSubsystemConfig.setSessionHeartbeatIntervalSeconds(5);
cpSubsystemConfig.setSessionTimeToLiveSeconds(300);
cpSubsystemConfig.setMissingCPMemberAutoRemovalSeconds(86400);
```

Client configuration:

```
final ClientConnectionStrategyConfig connectionStrategyConfig = config.getConnectionStrategyConfig();
connectionStrategyConfig.setAsyncStart(true);
connectionStrategyConfig.setReconnectMode(ClientConnectionStrategyConfig.ReconnectMode.ASYNC);

final ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
final List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
addresses.add("localhost:5701");
networkConfig.setAddresses(adresses);
networkConfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
networkConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(10);
networkConfig.setConnectionAttemptPeriod(5000);

final ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
config.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your CP Subsystem configuration is correct. It's described at [Hazelcast: CP Subsystem Configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/cp-subsystem/configuration.html#cp-subsystem-configuration).

Especially check if your `cp-member-count` and `group-size` is correct. If your `group-size` or `cp-member-count` is higher than the number of Hazelcast members you have in the cluster, than CP Subsystem won't work.

One weird thing is that the logs you see should be at the `FINE` level ([here is the code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.12.5/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/cp/internal/RaftService.java#L607)), but you see them as `WARN`.

If it does not help, please share your CP Subsystem configuration and the configuration of your Hazelcast client(s).

Comment: We only set cp-member-count (to 3). So per the documentation the group-size will also be three. Very strange that we see the line with level `DEBUG` even though according to the code we should see `FINE`. How could that be?

Comment: We're using Log4j2. I've checked the code and that explains why `FINE` is shown as `DEBUG`. `FINE` does not exist in Log4j2 and is mapped onto `DEBUG` inside `Log4j2Factory`.